# Receive all selected options from selelct control tagged multiple

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I have a form with a select control tagged with multiple. But when I receive the value it's only the first selected value, not multiple values as I expect. I expected ex "1,4,2"

**HTML:**

```
<form>  
        <select id="responsible" name="responsible" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="1">Bare hyggelig</option>
                <option value="3">BUA &#xD8;stensj&#xF8;</option>
                <option value="2">Et Levende Bogerud Beboerforening</option>
                <option value="4">Vennegruppe V&#xC5;R</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

**Action:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateActivity([FromForm] string responsible)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Calendar");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set action variable to string array and the value will contain all selected options.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateActivity([FromForm] string[] responsible)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Calendar");
}
```